# Need help in setting up an active RDP session

Tags: hyper-v, remote-desktop

I am facing an issue in my office hope someone can help me out with this.

we have Hyper-V server:deployed in 8 node cluster.

Our testing team runs UI based automation script (which requires 1920×1080 display resolution & Active RDP Session)

The problem is

1)Hyper-V doesn't support 1920×1080 display resolution & it can only support till 1600×1200.

2) if i use RDP i am getting 1920×1080 resolution but if i disconnect the RDP session Script execution is failing. So, i have used a 'tscon' powershell  script & scheduled task in windows task scheduler to trigger the script on disconnection of RDP.

The script is keeping RDP Session alive but as soon as RDP disconnects resolution is going back to 1600×1200 & UI automation script is failing..

Tried to use VNC but no luck because it is using Hyper-V display resolution...

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I think you are out of luck. Your requirements are a little on the fancy side - definitely out of the scope of what MS does with the Hyper-V connetions, so RDP it is. And you have outlined the issues with RDP very nicely. Even RemoteFX will not help as - it goes to RDP again.

That being said:

https://superuser.com/questions/1352039/how-do-i-prevent-lock-screen-of-remote-computer-when-remote-rdp-connection-into

points to RDP not blocking on terminal servers. And part of MSDN are those licenses, IIRC. It makes Hyper-V sort of moot (as every terminal server only connects one) but it may be a possible solution.

You could also keep the rdp sessions in ONE hyper-V client with the only purpose of holding the RDP sessions ;) THAT wlll be clumsy to manage ,though.